# BreezeJs - How to make simultaneous AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax, stored-procedures, breeze

I wrote two Ajax calls that request data from stored procedures (in SQL Server), `sp_ahtreatmentselect` and `sp_inventoryselect`. Here is how the functions look like in the Breeze controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("getinventories")]
public object GetInventories(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var data = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
    var opId = data["operationid"];
    string query = "sp_inventoryselect @operationId";
    SqlParameter operationId = new SqlParameter("@operationId", opId);
    return UnitOfWork.Context().ExecuteStoreQuery<GetInventories>(query, operationId);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("gettreatments")]
public object GetTreatments(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var data = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
    var opId = data["operationid"];
    string query = "sp_ahtreatmentselect @operationId";
    SqlParameter operationId = new SqlParameter("@operationId", opId);
    return UnitOfWork.Context().ExecuteStoreQuery<GetTreatments>(query, operationId);
}
```

Now, on client-side, the Ajax calls look like this:

```
var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

function treatments(id) {
    return ajaxImpl.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: serviceName + '/gettreatments',
        data: { operationid: id },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Success!');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('Error!');
        }
   });
}

function inventories(id) {
    return ajaxImpl.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: serviceName + '/getinventories',
        data: { operationid: id },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success!');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('Error!');
        }
    });
}

return inventories(id).then(treatments(id))
    .then(function() {
        // Do something
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        // Display error
    });
```

Both Ajax calls work fine, BUT problem is, `// Do something` is run BEFORE `inventories(id)` and `treatments(id)` are run. I would like it to work the other way around instead. I also tried `$.when(inventories(id), treatments(id)).then(...)` and `$.when(ajaxImpl.ajax(...), ajaxImpl.ajax(...)).then(...)`, but same problem occurs. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the issue lay on synchronous calls, not Breeze. I used *queue.js* to make Ajax calls and `// Do something` and the calls are completed. Here is how.

```
var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax'),
    serviceName = 'some/service',
    id = 1; // Could be any number

return queue()
    .defer(function(callback) {
        ajaxImpl.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: serviceName + '/getinventories',
            data: { operationid: id },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success!');

                callback(null, data);
        });
    })
    .defer(function(callback) {
        ajaxImpl.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: serviceName + '/gettreatments',
            data: { operationid: id },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success!');

                callback(null, data);
        });
    })
    .awaitAll(function(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error! ' + error);
        } else {
            // Do something, given that:
            // results[0] are inventories, and 
            // results[1] are treatments
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this has to do with Breeze. Did you get your `ajaxImpl` from a Breeze ajax adapter? I've looked at both ajax adapters shipped with Breeze and **neither of them returns *anything* from a call to the `ajax` method!**

Accordingly, you're expression should have died immediately with a reference error when it got to the `.then` in `return inventories(id).then(...`.  I don't see how it could have gotten to `\\ do something` at all.

Something isn't right with the way you've posed this question.

Once you get beyond this I still don't see how this involves Breeze. Breeze won't do anything with the results of your service requests.

I'm completely flummoxed by your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, `ajaxImpl` is a Breeze ajax adapter. And you are right, the issue has nothing to do with Breeze, it had to do with how I handled **promises** and **callbacks**. I finally found a workaround for the problem, using queue.js to run parallel Ajax calls before getting the results through a `callback` function. I will post it in a bit. If you have a better idea, please feel free to share. Thanks in advance.